# WPF Navigation between child views

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, navigation, prism

I have an application that consists of a shell, a content control that acts as a region and child content controls that goes into that. When the application loads, it starts in a file load view, and once a file is loaded a new region view is navigated to and appropriate child views.  The problem I'm having is getting back to the file load view.  I can get it to navigate to the file load view, but IsNavigatedFrom isn't called in the child view's VM, and this is causing problems because the child VM has ConfirmNavigationRequest to make sure that the user actually wants to leave that particular view.

Any ideas?

[edit] The button to go back to the file load view is in the parent content control.  I've tried putting it in the child but it causes too much redundancy[/edit]

Comment: Have you considered embedding your child control into Frame, which has built in support for navigation?

Comment: @David It's not so much the navigation that I'm having trouble with but the fact that IsNavigatedFrom and ConfrimNavigationReqeust in the child views aren't being hit when I click the 'Home' button (which is in the parent view)

Answer (score 0):

The IsNavigatedFrom will be called in the object that was used by your "RequestNavigate".
If you called RequestNavigate(view), then you can define IsNavigatedFrom in view.
If you want IsNavigatedFrom called in the ViewModel, then you need a viewmodel-first navigation.